# Eclipse Tabs Slightly Larger Than Four Spaces

Tags: eclipse, tabs, alignment, spaces

This is *not* a tabs vs. spaces issue.  It is simply that my Eclipse text editors (java, xml, text, etc.) do not line up their tabs with spaces properly.

Here is a screen shot where I typed the number '1' and followed it by three spaces on one line and a tab (set to four spaces) on the next line.
[image]

You can see that as the line length increases, the tab issue gets more pronounced.

Sometimes I find myself lining up lots of items on the right-hand side of
the screen, and it simply doesn't look right.  Has anyone else found this problem, and even more importantly a solution/work-around?  Or even better, know what settings I need to change to make the tabs and spaces jibe?

I'm running Eclipse Juno Service Release 1, Build id: 20121004-1855 on a Macintosh with the Android stuff, Mylyn, Eclipse Modeling Project, Egit, Webtools, CDT (C++), and Andrey Loskutov's color theme package installed (hence the white-on-black text).

Yeah, it sounds picky, but **why**?

One more thing: I just tested this with a fresh install of Eclipse Classic v. 4.2.2 (Juno) and the problem still persists.  (Hardware: iMac10,1 on Snow Leopard)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried different fonts?

Comment: Yes, this happens on both Monaco (what I currently use), Menlo, and Courier New.  Didn't see much point in testing further as all these fonts are used *everywhere*.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to mention: Eclipse is the **only** editor where this happens!  (And I have *many*!)

Answer (score 2):

I can't be completely positive, since I can't see your setup but I'd bet that this has something to do with the font you are using.  I'm using Source Code Pro fonts, and my tabs and spaces line up pretty well...

[image]

Comment: Yup, looks perfect there.  Can't hurt to try...hmmm, nice font.  But the problem persists.  Can you think of any settings that might affect this?

Comment: @Scott: I can't think of anything... but lord knows eclipse is full of hidden cupboards and forgotten spurs.  If this is really bugging you, you might try creating a new, fresh workspace, wo/customizations, and see if it happens there as well.  Good luck!

Comment: If nothing else, I have a *really* nice font to use--thanks for pointing me to the Source Code Pro fonts!